# How do I add an optional column in html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, time

I'm trying to make an appointment management using php and mysql 
so a user can register himself by filling a form. I have added a checkbox naming Mon, ) .Tue, Thu ... and gave two fields `time_from` and `time_to` (start time and end ti). I will split these time and store it in my db.

The problem is what if user have different timings on different days of the week like someone might work 9 - 5 on Monday to Friday and 11-2 on Saturday.

I want to capture these values when a user registers. Can I add an optional field in my html form or is there any other way I can do this.

[image]

My current code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name=fdadd method=post action=dsave.php> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DoctorName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Doctor Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name=name placeholder="Doctor Name" class="form-control" autofocus>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="femaleRadio" value="Female">Female
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="maleRadio" value="Male">Male
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="uncknownRadio" value="Unknown">Unknown
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /.form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Specilization" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Specilization</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="spec" name=spec placeholder="Specilization" class="form-control" autofocus>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="designation" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Designation</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="designation" name=desig placeholder="Designation" class="form-control" autofocus>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fee" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fee</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="fee" name=fee placeholder="Fee" class="form-control" autofocus>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="checkbox1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Available On</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Mon">Mon
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Tue">Tue
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Wed">Wed
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Thu">Thu 
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Fri">Fri
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Sat">Sat
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday" value="Sun">Sun

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="timef" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Available from</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="time" id="timef" name=timef class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="timet" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Available upto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="time" id="timet" name=timet class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" id="email" name=email placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="phone" name=phone placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address"  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="address" name=address placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="city" name=city placeholder="City" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="state" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="state" name=state placeholder="State" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" value=submit class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I even tried cloning the time fields with

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you got so far?  Can easily show you how it's done, and provide the code but that's not the point of this site.

Comment: You'll have to implement the possibility to set each day apart. You could spawn for example datetime fields for each day. Add maybe the possibility to mark dates with the same time so that the values won't have to be filled in twice?

Comment: you can use timepicker and change minTime and maxTIme dynamically depends on select days

Comment: You might clone that section of the form to create a new row with checkboxes, start and end times. Then also have a delete row function. Maybe also validation so each day is only once, or if repeated times don't overlap. You might need a naming scheme so names and IDs are unique when cloned, and other stuff…